# Office 2011 to 2016

Tags: ms-office, upgrade, macos

I upgraded to 2016 but it wasn't really an upgrade but a parallel install

Then i imported my default identify from outlook 2011 into the 2016 and 2016 is working fine and then i deleted my outlook 2011 identity to save space

Now i want to uninstall 2011

and i was trying to follow

[How to completely remove Office for Mac 2011](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2398768)

### Questions

1. Can i follow all the instructions from the above link and this will not break my 2016?
2. Or do i need to follow a subset of instructions or there are completely different instructions?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the [instructions for the removal of Office 2016 for Mac](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Uninstall-Office-2016-for-Mac-eefa1199-5b58-43af-8a3d-b73dc1a8cae3)
I think you can without a problem follow the instructions for removal of 2011.
I have quickly compared both instructions and did not see any matching folders being mentioned.

However, please compare it yourself and make a backup before you continue. I suggest you make a Time Machine backup and/or a clone of your drive before you continue.